# file attachment option required in infopath 2010 for forms created from sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

If I custumize a list in SharePoint2010 using Infopath2010, It does not allow me to attach files i.e. I cannot find the file attachment option in the control menu.

My form requires multiple attachments. 
I am new to infopath and sharepoint, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just drag and drop the attachment field onto the Infopath form. You can attach multiple files using this control.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180738.aspx) link for more info.

ALL attachments that you upload will be saved in this field and I am afraid there is no possibility to create additional "attachment" columns OOB in a SharePoint list. Check out [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/716c9d3b-3661-4244-b539-52026260b5f5) link.

[image: Infopath form]

Comment: yes... but I needed to have many of such attachments separately i.e. under different labels.

Answer (score 0):

Just happened by this answer. It IS possible to have multiple attachment fields in an InfoPath form -- I have that in an existing form I just modified for a client. So long as they have different data field names, they won't conflict at all.

Comment: How do you maintain different data fields for attachments in sharepoint?

Comment: @Neal: I saw that you answered a question regarding the ability to successfully add multiple 'attachments' data type fields in an InfoPath form. Thereby, when the published form is filled on sharepoint by a user, the list (in datasheet view) where the filled-in info goes shows multiple columns to represent those InfoPath 'attachments' data types.

How did you do that?